# Allowing Registration Page for Users Not Yet Registered

Tags: asp.net, authentication, registration

As I understand, when you want to authenticate users you need to add the following to webconfig.

```
 <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
        <allow users = "*" />
      </authorization>
```

Now, I have all the code to register users, which inserted them successfully into my DB as well as a login page that checks and allows them to browser as long as the proper credentials are inserted in the username and password fields.

What I want to do now is for the button that reads "Register" to redirect to my registration page, but this conflicts with the code above in regards to authorization, I researched and found that what needs to be done is create a folder and have the registrarion.aspx page inside and create a web.config file for said folder with the following parameters.

```
 <authorization>
        <allow users = "*" />
      </authorization>
```

My button has the code for redirecting which works in every other page once the user is authorized which is as follows:

```
 Response.Redirect("Register.aspx", true);
```

The button however, will not redirect to the register page, what other method of allowing users into register would work?

Upon further investigation, I find that the following code may conflict with what I want to do

```
<td>Username:</td>
 <td><input id="txtUserName" type="text" runat="server"></td>
      <td><ASP:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
           Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server" 
           ID="vUserName" /></td>
```

Both username and Password are required to enter, would this affect the redirect button even though the webconfig allows non-users into the registration page?

Comment: So what's your question? You stated a problem and then talked about what you did to solve the problem, but didn't state if it worked or not or what issues you currently face.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. The first `<system.web>` node is the default node in every Web.Config. In there you deny anonymous users access to the site with `<deny users="?"/>`.
But this will also block users to the register page and send the browser in a redirect loop.
But you can add a `<location>` node to the Web.Config and allow anonymous users access to the registration page with `<allow users="?"/>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="nl" culture="nl-NL" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="120" maxRequestLength="1024000" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="43200" loginUrl="/Register.aspx" defaultUrl="/Default.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: hello, I tried this and it did not work, I think it may be due to the username and password fields being requeired in the form, will add this ifnormation to the question.

Comment: Define "did not work"? The above snippet only allows anonymous users to access the login page. It has nothing to do with required fields in a form.